# Spyder Remote Kernel Processing

Tags: python, spyder

When connecting to a remote kernel through SSH in Spyder, does the processing all done in the remote kernel and not using the local machine's resources?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You mean a remote kernel through SSH?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That's correct, all computations are run in the server where the remote kernel was started and not in your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Just an additional inquiry, but when viewing data in the variable explorer will be limited to local machine's I/O and memory am I correct?

Comment: No, you need to start your remote kernel with the command `python -m spyder_kernels.console` (after installint `spyder-kernels`, of course) to have your the variable explorer working for it.